# Angular. Underline objects of array in textarea if value is false

Tags: javascript, angular6

I have an array of objects like this:

```
   list =[  
   {  
      name:"name1",
      value:true
   }   {  
      name:"name2",
      value:false
   }   {  
      name:"name3",
      value:true
   }   {  
      name:"name4",
      value:false
   }
]
```

What I want is to show inside a textarea each list.name and show it underlined if list.value == false.

What I tried was something like that:

```
<textarea *ngFor="let item of list" [ngClass]="{cssClass: item.value==false}">
{{item.name}}
</textarea>
```

AND

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list" [ngClass]="{cssClass: item.value==false}">
<textarea>
{{item.name}}
</textarea>
</div>
```

But there I'm getting one textarea per line and what I want is just one textarea with all the lines inside it

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Are you encountering any issue with your code ?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the post

Comment: why don't you use ``[ngStyle] `` as you want to manipulate only the text decoration ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a property in your .ts like:

```
dataToShow = this.list.reduce((acc, eachOb) => {
  if (eachOb.value === false) {
    acc += ` <u>${eachOb.name}</u> `
  }
  else {
    acc += ` ${eachOb.name} `
  }
  return acc
}, '')
}
```

And HTML as:

```
<div [contentEditable]="true" [innerHTML]="dataToShow"></div>
```

Add the `dataToShow` to show as innerHTML.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yrhh6p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Why would you complicate it like that ? **EDIT** My bad, didn't see the last part of the question

Comment: @trichetriche Text areas won't allow underline

Comment: yes they do, but as a whole, not on specific parts (try it yourself, you'll see !)

Comment: @trichetriche got it, will check it in a while!  Going out. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @xyz @trichetriche!! Last question: how could I do to check with a function the values of the array when typing, to see if they have changed???

Comment: State your goal rather than what you think is the solution :)

Comment: Why do you want to check if array values have changed ?

Comment: After showing the lines, if you type something, I want to run a function to check if you have added new elements of if you have changed the ones that were in the list

Comment: @trichetriche: Yes right! we can add css to the full `textarea` but not selectively to texts inside it.

Comment: @DOM: Can you be more specific about your full original requirement?